# angular-auth-oidc-client sso single logout not working

Tags: typescript, angular7, openid-connect, auth0, angular-auth-oidc-client

I am using angular-auth-oidc-client for authentication users through Auth0. This service has a logoff method which is clearing the browser cookies and localstorage but not actually logging off the user from Auth0. When I refresh the page, application is not redirected to Auth0 login page. I am using the below Logout URL. Please let me know what's wrong here.

https://mydomain.auth0.com/v2/logout?client_id=#CLIENTID#&returnTo=#REDIRECT_URL#&auth0Client=#AUH0_CLIENT#&federated

Comment: What happens when you logout? Where are you redirected? It sounds like you are not logging out of the auth0 session layer. This should be done using the URL you posted. Also you can see an example in this quickstart https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58824592/angular-auth-oidc-client-sso-single-logout-not-working

Comment: @DanWoda I am getting redirected to a custom logout page which i specified in Allowed logout url's. Please let me know how can i logout from auth0 session layer.

Comment: Are you getting an error back? Can you check in the auth0 logs that the logout is happening successfully on the auth0 level. You can find your logs in the dashboard under the 'logs' tab.